# scrollTop always returns 0 here

Tags: javascript

I want the cover title to move up as I scroll but currently I cant get the `scrollTop` to work. Using vanilla JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var coverTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.cover-title');
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    console.log(coverTitle.item(0).scrollTop);
  });
};
```

```css
.cover{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('img/cover.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.cover h1{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: serif;
  top: 70%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <h1 class="cover-title animate fadeIn">Some text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This might not be the entire problem, but you need to actually call the function scrollTop(). In console.log, you have scrollTop. It's a typo

Comment: @HadasZeilberger: [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) is a getter property, not a function.

Comment: Your issue is that the `coverTitle` elements never scrolls, so its `scrollTop` naturally doesn't change. You're scrolling the entire document, not just that element's content.

Comment: I tried using it with cover instead of cover-title class but the result is the same. Any idea why? It has a scrollbar in my body I am assuming.

Answer (score 2):

Here according to doc

> The Element.scrollTop property gets or sets the number of pixels that
>   the content of an element is scrolled upward. An element's scrollTop
>   is a form of distance measurement regarding an element's top to its
>   topmost visible content. When an element content does not generate a
>   vertical scrollbar, then its scrollTop value defaults to 0.

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

The very first point states that.

> If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow or if the
>   element has a property of  "non-scrollable"), scrollTop is set to 0.

Your element don't have any overflow property so it's naturally set scrollTop to 0.